# unable to print the address stored in unique pointer

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<memory>
using namespace std;

int main()
    {
        unique_ptr<int>unPtr1 = make_unique<int>(25);
        cout << unPtr1 << endl;//Line 8
        cout << *unPtr1 <<endl;


        system("pause>nul");
    }
```

At line 8 it shows `no operator "<<" matches these operands -- operand types are: std::ostream << std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int>>`.

Comment: use `unPtr1.get()` to get the owned pointer

Comment: Your title mentions the address stored *in* a unique pointer, but your code attempts to stream the unique pointer itself. It is important to be aware of small differences like that, as your computer is too stupid to realize that the difference is small.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out here [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rbvW975Gs)

Check the `get` method of the `unique_ptr`. The `get` method gives the raw pointer that the `unique_ptr` is encapsulating.

```
#include<iostream>

#include<string>

#include<memory>

using namespace std;
int main()

{
  std::unique_ptr < int > unPtr1 = make_unique < int > (25);
  std::cout << unPtr1.get() << std::endl;
  std::cout << * unPtr1;

  system("pause>nul");
}
```